# Lambda Function Cannot Be Assigned to Method

Tags: python, mypy

I have a python script from a Google API but when I run it, I get `error: Cannot assign to a method` on line that states:

```
request.get_method = lambda: method
```

Code block (Full code: https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/create-devices):

```
def create_delegated_credentials(user_email):
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
      SA_FILE,
      scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.devices'])

  delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(user_email)

  return delegated_credentials

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
dc = create_delegated_credentials(ADMIN_EMAIL)
dc.refresh(request)
print('Access token: ' + dc.token + '\n')

header = {...}
body = {...}

serialized_body = json.dumps(body, separators=(',', ':'))

request_url = BASE_URL + 'devices'
print('Request URL: ' + request_url)
print('Request body: ' + serialized_body)

serialized_body = json.dumps(body, separators=(',', ':'))
request = urllib.request.Request(request_url, serialized_body, headers=header)
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'                                   ############HERE
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please print the entire error message including the stack trace

Comment: `get_method` is a method defined in the standard Python `Request` class. Replacing it is extremely suspect. What do you aim to accomplish here?

Comment: So the full error is just "tests/__init__.py:178: error: Cannot assign to a method"
I'm running this in a Docker container with mypy on it. I believe the error is from that because it works perfectly fine when I run it on my local machine. 

As to Silvio's point, my only goal is to have the script work as intended. The code is directly from Google's API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of modifying the Request object (which `mypy` is helpfully erroring on as generally an assignment to a function is a mistake or a monkeypatch hack) you can set the `method` directly in construction of `Request`:

```py
request = urllib.request.Request(request_url, serialized_body, headers=header, method='POST')
```

this parameter was added in python3.3